# Linux headers generics

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, vmware-player

I have a trouble with the linux headers, when i use the command uname to check my version it is different from the version in usr/src/. I tried to download (with deleting the current version) but i couldn't because the version it's old. The root of the problem is that i can't start virtualbox o vmware because that reason. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

```
uname -r
3.13.0-35-generic

VmWare
Kernel headers for version 3.13.0-35-generic not found

usr/src$ ls
linux  linux-headers-3.16.0-24  linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic

/boot$ ls
abi-3.13.0-35-generic  config-3.13.0-35-generic  grub                             initrd.img-3.16.0-24-generic  memtest86+.elf            System.map-3.13.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
abi-3.16.0-24-generic  config-3.16.0-24-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic  memtest86+.bin                memtest86+_multiboot.bin  System.map-3.16.0-24-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic
```

Added Boot ls

Comment: can you include the content of `ls /boot/`

Comment: Yes! /boot$ ls
abi-3.13.0-35-generic  config-3.13.0-35-generic  grub                          initrd.img-3.16.0-24-generic  memtest86+.elf            System.map-3.13.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
abi-3.16.0-24-generic  config-3.16.0-24-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic  memtest86+.bin                memtest86+_multiboot.bin  System.map-3.16.0-24-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic

Thanks!

Comment: Yes i did that, when i run grub, i can choose the kernels, but the kernel 3.16 does not start :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you excute the command `sudo update-grub` it would update your grub boot list to point to the 3.16.0-35 kernel in the first place, hence it will be the default kernel.

what you have is a case where you booted in using 3.13 instead of the "latest on your machine" kernel which is 3.16.0-24

Comment: I did it, but i couldn't start with 3.13.0-35 kernel. It does not appear on the list when grub starts. it is included in the menu.lst

Comment: menu.lst is GRUB 1, modern versions of Ubuntu use GRUB2. Try reinstalling your bootloader and it should pick up grub.cfg with the newer kernel.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it today and it worked, i don't know why it didn't work 2 days ago

Comment: glad that it worked, i'm happy to help any time, welcome to AskUbuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently running a 3.1**3** kernel for which support was ended long ago. Try to install the `linux-generic` package which will pull in a kernel image and headers which matches each other. Then reboot.

Comment: When i try to install linux-generic it says i already have the lastest version

Answer (score 0):

You have to download proper kernel-headers.
From what I see in my Ubuntu there is a proper package:

linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP

apt-cache search linux-headers should show you what is available

apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic

should help you getting the proper linux-headers, I guess.

Or - maybe better  - update also your kernel and get proper headers and sources for it.

Comment: apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
don t have candidate to install

Comment: Have you added proper repos in your sources list? I guess that's where really problem is.

Comment: No i didn't, how can i do that?

Comment: Not sure which version of Ubuntu you use (kubuntu, ubuntu, xubuntu or something) - you can start your package manager in graphic environment and basically select proper repository server, then update packages.  Or you can edit manually /etc/apt/sources.list and put proper repo server there - but again it may depend on version.   This may help you:  http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ - generate proper sources.list and put them in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: After you put your repo sources into the file, run: apt-get update and check your headers once again. (or run apt-get dist-upgrade first, to get latest updates of software)

Comment: BUt how can i find the repository server? I'm on ubuntu 14.10 with unity. The repositories are the default.

Comment: You can either use those you can select in your package manager in graphic environment - or, as above - use the generator from the link I just gave you.